# Gmail like preloader

Tags: javascript

I have an SPA with heavy assets:

- One JavaScript file: 3Mb
- One Stylesheet file: almost 1Mb
- Two fonts: 700Kb

With a normal connection the files download quickly, less than 3 seconds. But you can imagine how the experience will be frustrating for a user with slow connection, he will probably end up closing the window.

One solution is to use a classic preloader like **Pace** but this is not still good enough.

#### My solution:

I would call a bit of code at different point of the big `script` file:

```
  console.log('progress at 0 %') // at the top
  // code to update the progress bar

  console.log('progress at 23 %') // Somewhere else
  // code to update the progress bar
```

and then at the bottom I just listen for `$(document).ready()` to remove the progress bar.

#### My question:

Is there a better solution, or a way to get **how much the user downloaded** and **how much left to download** from all the `scripts` `stylesheets` ... ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? like if the user closes the window and reopens it have the download pick up from where it left off?

Comment: 3MB of Javascript?  Sounds like a lot.  Are you minifying it?  Do you actually need it all, or are you just pulling in a ton of libraries haphazardly?

Comment: No, just a simple progress bar with a precise percentage of how much he downloaded.

Comment: @Marc I am caching all the **Angular** templates ( cause I do not have a the choice ) and some other heavy libraries, with minification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to include a smaller, inline bit of javascript that bootstrapped the rest of your application, you could use the XHR progress event.

Imagine this javascript inlined:

```
var appScript = document.createElement('script')
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
    var percent = e.loaded / e.total
    console.log('loaded', percent)
    // update loader
})
xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
    appScript.innerHTML = this.responseText
    document.body.appendChild(appScript)
    // ^ at this point the app javascript will run
})
xhr.open('GET', '/js/app.js')
xhr.send()
```

This should allow you to monitor the progress of your app being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: There isn't a better (existing) solution that monitors the precise percentage of the progress of the download of all of the resources in a document.

JoshWillik's answer referenced the XHR progress event which does offer possibility since it is possible to monitor the real-time progress of the download of resources in ajax requests ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress ). Naturally this would require the initial unmonitored download of the resources required to send those requests, monitor, calculate and render their collective progress and to load those resources upon completion (or whatever you wanted to do).

You also have have to account for a multitude of obstacles involving server configurations, the differences in media types, loading those types on the page in the correct order in relation to the others from the cache, the resources concerned by the ProgressEvent returning a length that can be calculated (lengthComputable), calculating the precise percentage real-time, lazy-loading and a wide arrangement of other factors involved in modern website and web application development techniques.

Many would argue that this type of functionality goes against UX principles and to focus on delivering the document and resources as quickly as possible (which I'm not against) but I would love to see something like this exist as well.

Alas we still have no jetpacks, flying cars nor real-time progress preloaders.

PS I've heard WebSocket mentioned in reference to a solution in another answer to a question such as this however I have not had time to look into it. Another idea is utilizing service workers.